# Inserting a new row with value extracted from column name

Tags: r, row, grepl

I have a dataset with column names such as: "b1_BAcid_20_494" "b1_BAcid_20_382"   "b1_BAcid_50_100" "b1_BAcid_50_360" "b1_BAcid_50_480" "b1_BAcid_50_750"   "b1_monoP_0.2_240" "b1_monoP_0.2_615" "b1_monoP_0.2_527" "b1_monoP_0.2_783".

I am trying to insert a new row that consists of the number between the two underscores for each column name, and then another row with just the compound name. For example, for "b1_BAcid_20_494", a want a row name "concentration" with value "20" and then a row name "compound" with a value "BAcid".

This is what I worked on:

```
df <- rbind(df, NA) #The dataframe has 500 rows, and I attached a new row with NA as values
rownames(df)[501] <- "concentration" #Named the new row "concentration".


if(grepl("_0.2_", colnames(ddf))){
  concentration <- 0.2
}else if (grepl("_10_", colnames(df))){
  concentration <- 10
}else if (grepl("_100_", colnames(df))){
  concentration <- 100
}else if (grepl("_2_", colnames(df))){
  concentration <- 2
}else if (grepl("_20_", colnames(df))){
  concentration <- 20
}else{
  concentration <- 50
}
```

These if-else statements didn't work for "concentration", and I wanted to do something similar for the row "compound" also.

Comment: Adding a row of all names will convert any non-string column to string, is that intentional? That is, `rbind(data.frame(P=pi), data.frame(P="pi"))` results in the `P` column being `c("3.14159265358979", "pi")` (i.e., number a number in the first row). Are you doing that intentionally?

Comment: For reasons mentioned by @r2evans above, have you considered transposing your data? This way the column names are the row names and you have a column for concentration and a column for compound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up front, adding a row of the compound name will convert all non-string columns to strings. For instance,

```r
str(rbind(data.frame(P=pi), data.frame(P="pi")))
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  1 variable:
#  $ P: chr  "3.14159265358979" "pi"
```

where we can no longer use `3.14159...` as a number (without work). Assuming that you're okay with that ...

We can use `strcapture` to extract the compound and concentration, then convert it to rows of a frame.

```r
vec <- c("b1_BAcid_20_494", "b1_BAcid_20_382", "b1_BAcid_50_100", "b1_BAcid_50_360", "b1_BAcid_50_480", "b1_BAcid_50_750", "b1_monoP_0.2_240", "b1_monoP_0.2_615", "b1_monoP_0.2_527", "b1_monoP_0.2_783")
tmp <- strcapture(".*_(.*)_(.*)_.*", vec, list(compound="", conc=0))
tmp
#    compound conc
# 1     BAcid 20.0
# 2     BAcid 20.0
# 3     BAcid 50.0
# 4     BAcid 50.0
# 5     BAcid 50.0
# 6     BAcid 50.0
# 7     monoP  0.2
# 8     monoP  0.2
# 9     monoP  0.2
# 10    monoP  0.2

newrows <- setNames(data.frame(t(tmp)), vec)
newrows
#          b1_BAcid_20_494 b1_BAcid_20_382 b1_BAcid_50_100 b1_BAcid_50_360 b1_BAcid_50_480 b1_BAcid_50_750 b1_monoP_0.2_240 b1_monoP_0.2_615 b1_monoP_0.2_527 b1_monoP_0.2_783
# compound           BAcid           BAcid           BAcid           BAcid           BAcid           BAcid            monoP            monoP            monoP            monoP
# conc                20.0            20.0            50.0            50.0            50.0            50.0              0.2              0.2              0.2              0.2
```

You can `rbind` newrows to your existing frame assuming that those are the *only* columns in the original data. If you have other columns not referenced in our `vec`, then you have options:

1. Create the not-yet-included columns in this `newrows`, in the correct order, with some reasonable value (`NA`, `""`, `0`, whatever makes sense with y our data).
2. Use `dplyr::bind_rows(orig, newrows)` or `data.table::rbindlist(list(orig, newrows), fill=TRUE, use.names=TRUE)`, as both will work around the not-included names in your `orig` frame.